# How to load and bind a texture with Qt's OpenGL classes?

Tags: qt, opengl, qt5

I'm working on a simple OpenGL application using Qt5, and I've used the new QOpenGL classes to handle my vertex buffers, index buffers and shaders. I'm a little stuck on textures, though.

I have my QOpenGLBuffer and QOpenGLShaderProgram... but where's QOpenGLTexture? No such class seems to exist in the [Qt5 class list](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/classes.html). Do I have to resort to direct OpenGL calls for managing textures?

Comment: After having submitted my answer, I realized that the title and content of your question are somewhat inconsistent: the [Qt OpenGL module](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtopengl/qtopengl-index.html) contains the 'old' QWidget based interface to OpenGL, including the `QGLWidget::bindTexture(...)` functionality. The new Qt5 _QOpenGL*_ classes are part of the new [Qt Gui module](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtgui/qtgui-index.html). I am new to this: can one update the question title for clarification?

Comment: I removed the word 'module' from the title. I would have been ok with answers pointing me to anything in Qt Gui or Qt OpenGL (despite that QtOpenGL is mostly deprecated).

Comment: @axxel It's interesting that you mention `QGLWidget::bindTexture(...)`, since it would be a pretty reasonable solution had I been subclassing QGLWidget. Unfortunately, since I'm rendering behind a QQuickView, it would be rather difficult to use that.

Comment: You are right, the `QGLWidget::bindTexture(...)` hint does not really help there but please have a look at my revised answer below. Maybe it is not that difficult - easier than going the Qt3D way, I hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is right: no such class exists in the QtGui module of Qt5. And yes, you have to resort to plain OpenGL calls to handle your textures if you don't want to pull in the widget library.

That being said, the current (let's say somewhat non-optimal and inconsistent) situation is recognized and actively being discussed by the Qt developers. See Sean Harmer's [OpenGL in Qt 5.1 and onwards](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2012-December/008765.html) mail, specifically point 7. But following that thread and having a look at the current dev tree, I doubt it is going to land in 5.1.

---

Edit: Looking at the other answers and the recent comments I'd like to add regarding options you have with standard Qt 5.0:

Is your main goal to:

1. get some pointer you can pass to `glTexImage2D(..., GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_RGBA, pointer)` from your potentially 'weird' formatted QImage? or
2. use some helper class that spares you dealing with `glTex*()` related functions?

If it is the first and linking the (old) OpenGL module (which is part of Qt 5.0) is an option (and apart from 'esthetically' reasons, I don't see why it would not be), you could use the static `QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(QImage)` that Victor was hinting at. If not, then doing something like that function does 'by hand' (along the lines of what Xīcò suggested) should work: basically first calling `QImage::convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32)` and then add some platform dependent byte swizzeling and mirroring (see *convertToGLFormatHelper(...)* in [the source](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/opengl/qgl.cpp)). Although, if you happen to use your own shaders, then doing that on the GPU is way faster.

If you want to have both *and* linking the mentioned OpenGL Qt 5.0 add-on module is an option you might be able to actually use a `QGLWidget::bindTexture(...)` equivalent even in your QQuickView class:

```
GLuint texID = QGLContext::fromOpenGLContext(
                   this->openglContext())->bindTexture(...)
```

Where `this` would be a QQuickView*. See the [QGLContext help](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtopengl/qglcontext.html). (Disclaimer: I have not tried that myself.)

Comment: I actually did resort to plain OpenGL calls. This wasn't the first answer that told me that, but it was most well written. Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

`QImage` has direct support for OpenGL-friendly format which can be supplied to glTexImage..() functions.

See chapter 6 remarks [here](http://digitalfanatics.org/projects/qt_tutorial/chapter14.html).

So yes, direct OpenGL calls can/should be used.

Comment: Ick. To convert QImages to OpenGL format in my non-widget app, I have to include QGLWidget? And it's a function that states it returns a QImage that cannot be used as a QImage? And on top of that, I have to mix Qt's OpenGL wrappers with raw calls just to show a basic textured cube? These are still early days for Qt5, I guess.

Comment: It would a big discussion about the need to wrap every OGL feature in Qt. Qt creates the GL context, but then it is not a 3D engine. So some low-level calls seem appropriate to me.

Answer (score 1):

> Ick. To convert QImages to OpenGL format in my non-widget app, I have to include QGLWidget?

Depending on your machine endianness and on the OpenGL format you want, you can use a formulation like:

`QImage gl_compatible_image = standard_image.rgbSwapped ().mirrored ();`

for instance, to map a `Format_RGB32` QImage into a `GL_RGBA` texture on an Intel machine.

Comment: What do you means by Ick. ?

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly 'Ick' is an exclamation used to express disgust.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the class I'm looking for is [`QGLTexture2D`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt3d-1.0/qgltexture2d.html), which is a part of Qt3D. Unfortunately, as axxel mentions, it is not a part of Qt 5.0, and may not make it into Qt 5.1.

That said, I could [retrieve and build Qt3D](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt3d-1.0/qt3d-building.html) myself. I could then use `QGLTexture2D` in a manner very similar to the `QOpenGLBuffer` and `QOpenGLShaderProgram` I already have.

Answer (score 1):

[QOpenGLTexture was added in Qt 5.2](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopengltexture.html).